# Image won't update when looped

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm quite new to the whole React Native and JS stuff so I might be making a silly mistake here. I have the following code that I got from here: https://reactnativecode.com/change-image-source-dynamically/

The code is a little bit adjusted as I want it to loop.

**The problem is as follows**: It changes the first time. Then when clicked again it changes the URL (as I have it in a Text component) but the image doesn't show up again. Then when pressed again (3th time) the Text (variable name) won't change anymore and the image will still not show up.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { StyleSheet, View, Text, Image, Button, Platform, TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      imageURL: 'https://reactnativecode.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Guitar.jpg'
    }
  }

  Load_New_Image = () => {
    if (this.state.imageURL == 'https://reactnativecode.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Guitar.jpg'){
      this.setState({
        imageURL: 'https://reactnativecode.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/motorcycle.jpg'
      })
    }else{
      this.setState({
        imageURL: 'https://reactnativecode.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/Guitar.jpg'
      })
    }
  }

  render() {
    console.log('source: ', this.state.imageURL)
    return (
      <View style={styles.MainContainer}>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.Load_New_Image}>
        <Image
          key={this.state.imageURL}
          source={{ uri: this.state.imageURL }}
          style={styles.imageStyle} />
        </TouchableHighlight>

        <Text>{this.state.imageURL}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

  MainContainer: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: (Platform.OS) === 'ios' ? 20 : 0,
    margin: 10
  },

  imageStyle: {
    width: 200,
    height: 300,
    resizeMode: 'center'

  }

});
```

Comment: the imageURL of else statement is not working

Comment: Such a silly copy paste mistake of mine. Thanks for your answer.